# Iteraiting a list and searching the count

Tags: java

Hi i have list of size three say

```
 List<Long> s  = new Arraylist<Long>();
        now s.size()=3;
```

now i have another list which is of type long

```
List<Long> l = new ArrayList<Long>();

l.add(101l);
l.add(102l);
l.add(102l);
l.add(103l);
l.add(103l);
l.add(103l);
l.add(104l);
l.add(104l);
l.add(104l);
```

Now since 103 is repeating 3 times and is equal to the size of s i want 103 and 104 is repeating thrice i want 103 and 104 only how to do that???

Comment: And what do you mean "i want 103 and 104"? You want to return them in a list? You want to print them? It would also be nice if you tried reformating your question a little ;)

Comment: I want to return a list

Comment: Please share you present code..

Answer (score 0):

1.You can sort the list

2.Traverse the list and check the frequency of the previous element if the current element is not equal the previous.

3.If the frequency equals the size of the required list ,add it to the another list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use : [`Collections.frequency`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object))

```
List<Long> newList = new ArrayList<>();
for(Long item : l)
    if(Collections.frequency(l, item) == s.size()) 
        newList.add(item);
return newList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 List<Long> l = new ArrayList<Long>();
 l.add(101l);
 l.add(102l);
 l.add(102l);
 l.add(103l);
 l.add(103l);
 l.add(103l);
 l.add(104l);
 l.add(104l);
 l.add(104l); 

  //use below code, on iterating valueCount map you will get each value number of occurance.

       Map<Long,Integer> valueCount=new HashMap<Long,Integer>;

       for(Long value:l){

       if(valueCount.contains(value))
       {
        int count=valueCount.get(value);
        i++;
        valueCount.put(value,count);
       }else
       {
        valueCount.put(value,1);
       }
      }

     // iterate map and get count of each value
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Collections Util frequency Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object)) find the repeated values inside the Collection list.

Please find the working code below.

```
    List<Long> nonDuplicateList = new ArrayList<Long>();

    nonDuplicateList.add(101L);
    nonDuplicateList.add(102L);
    nonDuplicateList.add(102L);
    nonDuplicateList.add(103L);
    nonDuplicateList.add(103L);
    nonDuplicateList.add(103L);
    nonDuplicateList.add(104L);
    nonDuplicateList.add(104L);
    nonDuplicateList.add(104L);

    System.out.println("Original list " + nonDuplicateList);

    List<Long> repeatedList = new ArrayList<Long>();
    for (Long longValue : nonDuplicateList) {
        if (Collections.frequency(nonDuplicateList, longValue) > 2) {
            if (!repeatedList.contains(longValue)) {
                repeatedList.add(longValue);
            }

        }
    }
    System.out.println("Duplicated List " + repeatedList);
```

Output is

```
Original list[101, 102, 102, 103, 103, 103, 104, 104, 104]
Duplicated List [103, 104]
```